# Should a Buddhist go to the gym?

Tags: modern-world, well-being

I have to be honest with you, this question was already answered by an authority on Buddhism and long-time practitioner, which is the spiritual leader of the Sangha which I meditate with. And yet, I feel the need to listen to other opinions.

The question is the one in the title. His main argument was that going to the gym is not beneficial in any way and it actually worsens us by feeding our pride, thus making the schism between ourselves and vain glory more difficult to realize.

What do you think?

Comment: See also [Physical Exercise as a Monk?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3301/254)

Comment: I think this question has already been asked and answered at, [What buddhism says about bodybuilding (and weights training)?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10803/254) and/or at [Buddhist practice and physical exercises](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9445/254)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I think I gathered enough material to make up my mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think it depends on the attitude and the frame of mind

a care to keep in mind the fact that it's a business of maintaining fitness of a frail and mortal bag of bones and impurities may negate the tendency of the attachment to body and self-association with it to become stronger, which such type of activity in my opinion is prone to foster

but if one IS a Buddhist they must be able to skilfully counteract that tendency

in any case the motive for going to gym for a Buddhist should not be improvement of bodily appearance but rather health considerations in the frame of mind along the lines of the attitude to eating recommended for monks in the suttas

> And how does a monk know moderation in eating? There is the case where a monk, considering it appropriately, takes his food not playfully, nor for intoxication, nor for putting on bulk, nor for beautification, but simply for the survival & continuance of this body, for ending its afflictions, for the support of the holy life, thinking, 'I will destroy old feelings [of hunger] & not create new feelings [from overeating]. Thus I will maintain myself, be blameless, & live in comfort.

*Aparihaniya sutta (AN 4.37)*

Answer (score 3):

If the mind is pure and the intention (cetana) is wholesome, then the result will also be wholesome.

[With reference to the twin verses in the Dhammapada.](http://www.buddhanet.net/dhammapada/d_twin.htm)

[image]